# add CiviCRM extensions to local site

Tags: drupal, cividiscount

I am working on a redesign of an existing site.  I've gone ahead and created a local site and imported the CiviCRM database.  The client wants to allow the user to add a discount code while subscribing to an on-line magazine (part of the redesign).  I've followed these directions https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Extensions and got to installing the manage extensions page where when I click on the install CiviDiscount Module Extension it redirects me to the log in page on the live site.

I am thinking that there must be a configuration issue somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes CiviCRM sends you to an absolute URL, even though most of the time you navigate through links with relative URLs.

CiviCRM uses the base URL in your civicrm.settings.php file to build the absolute URLs, and it caches that base URL for performance.  I suspect that your situation is either:

- the base URL in the settings file still points to the live site, or
- the cache still has the live site URL even though you updated the settings file.

To fix this, confirm that the settings file has the right URL, and then visit **Administer > System Settings > Clear caches and update paths**.  Update the paths there, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks Andrew that did the trick.  Any chance that you could point me in the direction of documentation for using the CiviDiscount extension.  We are trying to add a discount code to a subscribe to an online magazine page and most of the documentation I have seen leaves me scratching my head.  In particular how do you add it to a specific page